# In Canada, is it possible to discontinue an civil action against only one of the defendants?

Tags: canada, civil-procedure

In a Civil matter where multiple defendants are involved, is it possible to discontinue the case against only one of the defendants, after the pleadings are closed ?

if it is possible, then is a motion hearing and an order required ?

Is a reason required for discontinuance ?

Comment: the answer to the first question is yes.